# replacing html classes in a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I need to be able to manipulate a variable which contains html which i will be applying to the DOM prior to applying to the DOM.

I have retrieved a handlebar template and compiled and applied a JSON object. resulting in a var containing the markup to be applied to the DOM.

Unfortunately jQuery cannot manipulate this output. Is there a way I can get jQuery to treat this variable as html so i can manipulate it prior to adding to the DOM?

example below

```
var htm = '<section><div></div></section>';
$('div',$(htm)).addClass('smurf');
alert(htm);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var htm = '<section><div></div></section>';
var $htm = $(htm);
$htm.find("div").addClass('smurf');
htm = $("<div>").append($htm).html();
alert(htm);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mf5JC/

The problem with your code is that jQuery doesn't modify strings in place, as you expect. You have to work around that by creating a jQuery element, manipulating it (adding the class to the child div), and getting the content.

What your code did was:

1. Take the HTML string and put it in a new jQuery object
2. Find any `<div>` descendants in that HTML
3. Add the class "smurf" to the matched elements
4. Alert the original `htm` HTML string

Notice how it was operating on the new jQuery object. When creating a jQuery object, it doesn't keep some reference to the original string, so it doesn't/can't modify it. If you separate the logic out, like with the code I provided, you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a string, constructing a jQuery object from it (which makes a DOM from the string), modifying the DOM and then alerting the *original string*.

If you want to get the modified code you need to serialise it back to a string.

```
var htm = '<section><div></div></section>';
var jHtm = $(htm);
jHtm.find('div').addClass('smurf');
// Add to a div so that we can get the innerHTML of that div
var div = jQuery('<div>').append(jHtm);
alert(div.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach *should* work, but it's not going to affect the `htm` variable; you'll want to add the resulting jQuery object to the DOM instead:

```
var htm = '<section><div></div></section>';
var $htm = $(htm);
$('div', $htm).addClass('smurf');
$('body').append($htm);
```